# Github profile contribution graph commits from accepted PR

Tags: github

Just have a quick questions about the contributions graph on Github profiles. If I forked a repo then created a branch in that fork and did all my work/commits in there then had that branch in my fork merged into the original repo master branch via a pull request should those commits show up on my contribution graph now?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile/) should answer your query.

Based of that guidelines, if your codes are being merged into the master, the commits/contribution will show up.

To confirm that, your pull request will show up as a valid contribution anyways.